# Does the wrapper.conf setting for max memory specify the setting for the entire mule server or for an individual app deployed on the server?

Tags: mule

Looking at the wrapper.conf for Mule ESB, does the wrapper.java.maxmemory setting specify the max heap size for the entire Mule server or for a given application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for the entire server, which is the Java application that's being "wrapped".